# Stepping down as moderator

Tags: discussion, moderators

Although I think we probably need 2 new mods just to replace Federico, the second spot being filled in the election is mine. Since I was elected moderator I have found myself with less and less time to spend here, especially recently. Because of that, as well as some personal reasons, I decided that with Federico retiring this would be a good time for me to go as well. I will keep sticking around until the election is finished.

It wasn't an easy decision, I would love to just keep doing what I can, but I think it's best to give the spot to someone else that is able to put more into the role right now. I am hoping that some of our established users will step up to help keep the community running smoothly going forward.

Answer (score 9):

Thank you very much for moderating our site!

Answer (score 9):

Thank you for the help provided and the time you've been able to dedicate! :)